# Android Device Manager problems starting on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio

I am developing a MAUI app in Visual Studio 2022.  Visual Studio has the function whereby the user runs the MAUI app in an Android Emulator.  This opens a separate software called the Android Device Manager.  I have used the Android Device Manager on-and-off for six months.  Sometimes it starts, sometimes not.  I have finally bit the bullet and tried to get the installation fixed.  I started with a fresh Windows 10 install, added all updates, installed Hyper-V.  Downloaded a new installation application for Visual Studio 17.5.  Installed the application using Administrator privileges.  The Android Device Manager runs but with errors.  I have spent many days trying to find a fix for this without success.

Something like: "Android 13.0 – API 33" system image is incomplete therefore the device "Pixel 5 - API 33" could not be created.  Do you want us to reinstall the image?

Comment: Unstable connection perhaps? It would try to download the rather large images and some ISP fucked up the CDN connection.

Comment: I have downloaded the Visual Studio 2022 installation software a number of times and tried different versions of the Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Windows was re-installed.  Visual Studio was deleted and installed six times.

Comment: I believe the system images themselves are downloaded separately. Does it error on all variations of the Android 13 image?